# Is my ES6 import reading from index file or directly from the exporting file?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, export, es6-class

Given the directory structure and files below:

1. Is that index file valid given that there are two different types of `export`s?
2. Is the `myUtil` import in `test.ts` reading from the `index.ts` file in `src/MyModel`? Or is it reading directly from `src/MyModel/modelUtils`?

```
src
|
-- test.ts
-- MyModel
   |
   -- MyModel.ts
   -- index.ts
   -- modelUtils.ts
```

MyModel.ts

```
// create a class here called MyClass
export default MyClass
```

modelUtils.ts

```
export const myUtil = function () => {}
```

index.ts

```
export { default } from './MyModel'
export * as ModelUtils from './modelUtils'
```

test.ts

```
import MyClass from 'src/models/MyModel'
import { myUtil } from 'src/models/modelUtils'
```

Comment: Well it's certainly valid to re-export using multiple forms. People do it all the time because the modules there are re-exporting from use different styles of exports. However, as an old fashioned curmudgeon, I think `* from` exports are just plain evil because they will silently break if you introduce a member with the same name in multiple modules you're exporting from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Each file can only have one default export. It can also not have name classes. Both conditions are met so it should be valid. There is more information about options here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export
2. There seems to be a typo in the tree structure provided. The path `src/models/MyModel.ts` does not exist, but `src/MyModel/index.ts` does. Assuming it is `src/models/MyModel` and the directory exists, **the main problem is that the path (`src/models/MyModel`) is not relative**. When using an absolute path it will always look into the `node_modules`, for the path to be relative it would need to start with `./` or `../`, in this case: `./models/MyModel`, in which case it would import `MyModel.ts` file.